# How to install VMware Workstation 9 on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: vmware

How can I install `VMware-Workstation-9.0.0-812388.x86_64.bundle` on Ubuntu 12.04?
I ran the following steps in the terminal:

```
ls  
cd Downloads  
sudo sh VMware-Workstation-9.0.0-812388.x86_64.bundle
```

... and when I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> the command line returned to the Downloads folder.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download your installer.
2. Open the Terminal (Dash Home > Search for Terminal)
3. Change the file permission to make it executable

   ```
   chmod 755 VMware-Workstation-Full-9.x.x.x86_64.bundle
   ```
4. Install workstation

   ```
   sudo ./VMware-Workstation-Full-9.x.x.x86_64.bundle
   ```
5. Then follow the simple installation steps.

[(Source)](http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/install-vmware-workstation-9-on-centos-6-rhel-6.html#axzz2h8aLKvbZ)